# Rails 7 - Routing error while creating a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am seeing a routing error while creating a new record. I am unable to understand why Rails is considering a POST request as GET. Below are the details:

I have a form as mentioned below:

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: home_new_user_path, method: :post do |f|%>

<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>

<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Enter name", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1', autocomplete: "off" %>

<%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Enter email", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1', autocomplete: "off" %> 


<%= f.text_field :password, placeholder: "Enter password", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1', autocomplete: "off" %>


<%= f.text_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Enter password to confirm", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1', autocomplete: "off" %>

<%= f.submit %>

<%end%>
```

Below is the Routes.rb

```
  post 'home/new_user', to: 'home#new_user'
```

Below is the controller method:

```
  def new_user
   user_to_be_created = User.create!(name: params[:name], email: params[:email], password: params[:password], password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])
  end
```

View code to access this controller method:

```
<%= link_to "New user", home_new_user_path, method: :post %>
```

However, I get a routing error as below:

```
No route matches [GET] "/home/new_user"
```

Comment: Are you getting that routing error when submitting the form, or clicking the "new user" link? If it's the latter, that's to be expected; the Rails `link_to` helper doesn't support a `method` parameter, and neither does the HTML anchor tag it usually generates. Forms can POST, links can only GET

Comment: I highly recommend trying out [Ruby on Rails' scaffolding](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-generate) first (for example with `bin/rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`) to get an idea of how Rails' controller, views, and naming conventions look like and what an idiomatic Rails' app would look like.

Comment: In addition to @spickermann's suggestion I would really recommend that you read the [Getting Started with Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). You've been posting a lot of questions recently and what they have in common is that you're fighting the framework instead of leveraging it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rails link\_to using get instead of post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137795/rails-link-to-using-get-instead-of-post)

Answer (score 2):

You might be using Rails but the code that you're writing is not Rails code.

In Rails creating a record is handled by two separate actions which are `new` and `create`:

```
HTTP Method   Path         Description
----------------------------------------------------------------
GET           /users/new   Renders a form which is used to create a user.
POST          /users       Responds to form submissions and creates the user
```

The `new` action displaying the form uses GET since its an idempotent action. It doesn't create or modify anything and looks the same to all visitors.

Actually creating the record is done by posting the form to the collection path (`/users`). If the record is not valid the new view is rendered as a response - but this time it should contain the error messages from the validations.

You can generate these routes by using the resources macro:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
```

Linking to the new action is done with:

```
<%= link_to "New user", new_user_path %>
```

By convention you would then respond to these requests in UsersController.

Bunching everything in your application into a god class HomeController is just not a good practice.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # @todo authorize that the current user should be allowed to create users

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /users/new
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to '/somewhere' # @todo replace with actual path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(
            :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
          )
  end
end
```

Your form should also use the conventions:

```
# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with model: @user do |f|%>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
 
      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%# do not use placeholders as labels. It's a huge accessibilty anti-pattern %>
    <%= f.label :name %> 
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1', autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1', autocomplete: "off" %> 
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password, class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1', autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1', autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div class="action"> 
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
# app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: "form" %>
```

When you pass an instance of User Rails will check if the model is persisted and automatically set the request method to POST and derive the correct route `users_path` from the class name. By not explicitly setting either you can reuse the same form for editing.

### However

If you're planning on actually using this in a production app I would really recommend that you use [Devise::Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) instead. It removes the hassle and potential security hazard of requiring admins to set the users password and then communicate the password with the users.

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There is no information about admins in the question:)

Comment: @mechnicov I took the liberty of filling in some of the blanks with the askers previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096152/rails-7-devise-overriding-registrations-controller

Comment: @mechnicov but you're correct. The question could also be read as an attempt to create a user signup.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 7 with turbo you should use `data-turbo-method="post"` attribute to make JavaScript magic with link

```rb
<%= link_to "New user", home_new_user_path, data: { turbo_method: :post } %>
```

Less magic would be happen if you use form instead of link. For this purpose you can use `button_to` helper

```rb
<%= button_to "New user", home_new_user_path, method: :post %>
```

---

And BTW your

```rb
post 'home/new_user', to: 'home#new_user'
```

is not RESTful route, probably is better to use

```rb
resources :users, only: :create
```

Comment: While this does solve the immediate problem using POST like this will just create a bunch of new issues down the road. Since no parameters are sent along it will blow up as soon as strong parameters are used (the current parameter assignment doesn't  even work). And if you work your way around that one and start displaying errors on the form the user gets an unpleasant face full of validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting non-GET requests via `link_to` requires JS or Turbo, as stated by the [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

> Supported verbs are `:post`, `:delete`, `:patch`, and `:put`. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET.

You should really be using `button_to` instead of `link_to`. Re-wiring a `link_to` to send a POST request will be a hassle and require JS.

[This tutorial](https://jmlovitsch.medium.com/creating-a-button-in-rails-e26f67b3d79a) Shows you how to make a post/put request using button_to

Comment: That still just pushes the problem down the road. What they actually should be doing is using a link and separate GET and POST routes.

Comment: using a link for a POST request seems like an anti-pattern to me. A link should be for GETing a resource

Comment: I'm saying there should be a separate route that responds to GET that you link to as per the Rails conventions. Not that they should be using Turbo/Rails UJS to make it POST. The only real reason to use Turbo's method override on links IMHO besides legacy code is to get around the limitation in HTML that forms can not be nested.

Comment: What Rails conventions? I don't think having a distinct POST and GET path is necessary, to create an article resource you submit POST /articles/ and to view all article resources you submit a GET /articles/ that is the same path and REST compliant